# Task on marathon never ends

Tags: docker, containers, mesos, marathon

I am new to mesos , marathon framework. I formed the cluster with three mesos(0.27.0) masters and two mesos slaves. Marathon (0.15.1)  is installed on masters. I scheduled one task from marathon UI  of echoing Hello in some file    `echo "hello" > /tmp/sample.txt`.
I observed that the `hello` is written in the file but the process of writing `hello` inside the file is going on. Ideally it should be stopped once it has written. I have same trouble when I tried to launch the containers, the containers are getting created till I have no memory. Can anyone suggest me what to do in order to stop echoing and to stop marathon from creating new containers ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Is your task not finishing once the command finishes? e.g. blocks forever? or is it rescheduled immediately and you have lots of tasks in state finished? If the latest - it's the desired behavior for Marathon and you actually cannot change this. You could probably take a look at Aurora or Chronos for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour for Marathon, which is meant to be used for long-running tasks, that is things like a Web server, app server, etc.

When Marathon sees the app terminates, it will launch it again (potentially on a different node).

For one-shots, you can use [Chronos](http://mesos.github.io/chronos/), [Cook](https://github.com/twosigma/Cook) or write your own framework.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That's fine. But in case of launching containers it is go on consuming hardware. Is there any other way to do by using marathon only. I think there should be as they have provided special support for docker containers.

Comment: No, it's not because this is the wrong tool for it. We (as in Mesosphere, the company behind Marathon) have a chat at http://chat.mesosphere.com/ where you're welcome to discuss your use case and any follow-up questions, if you want.